# Redirect to another page on select event

Tags: jquery, html

How can i redirect on another page when an option is selected from a select element.

HTML select:

```
<select id='rooms' class="full-width">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

What i need is to redirect users to page.php when they select the option 2, 3, 4

Comment: Use change event of select the simply use `window.loaction.href="Your path"`

Comment: Simply you can use `.change` event (jQuery) of dropDown and on selection of particular value, you can redirect to another page, what's the issue in that?

read more about change event :http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: the downvote is because there are tons of examples on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `window.location.assign` in the `change` event handler of that `select`. I also presume you would need to add the value selected to the URL so that the next page knows what option was selected; for that you can use `val()`. Try this:

```
$('#rooms').change(function() {
    window.location.assign('page.php?rooms=' + $(this).val());
});
```